# Chef Architecture Configuration Windows

Tags: windows, automation, server, chef-infra

We have a windows environment here and I was looking into Chef CM solution as it has significantly strong Windows support comparing to others. I know that it can use Server/Client configuration or just chef-solo. Ideally, I would like to have a distributed environment and be able to manage my Windows nodes from a centralized server.

It looks like chef server is not available on Windows and I would like to ask if there is a way to bypass Linux and only have chef running on pure Windows environment? Is there other way to setup centralized chef repository with all the recipes, cookbooks, etc that would be running on Windows or Linux part is essential to fully implement Chef? Is it doable to run just chef-solo but have a centralized version controlled chef repository synced with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Chef Solo](http://docs.chef.io/chef_solo.html) or also [Chef Client in local mode](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/10/31/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds/) (a.k.a. `chef-zero`, preferred ofer `chef-solo` by many people) should be able to fulfil your needs. You would just have to either update an, e.g., Git repository or download an archive containing all the cookbooks and run let them apply by `chef-solo`/ `chef-zero`.

Chef server is not available for Windows. If it is an option, you can make use of [Hosted Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/#plans-and-pricing).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know that it is not ideal and comes with some limitations as opposed to have a Chef server but seems like it is doable. As I understand, I would have to manage a remote git repository and then pull the cookbooks for every node I want to provision correct? Also, I have noticed two terms: Chef Solo/Zero and Chef Client in local mode, what is the main difference between the two? Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are people that explicitly use _no_ chef server. It's just a different way to resolve cookbook dependencies. Have you read the article about chef local mode (local mode equals chef-zero, in contrast to the historic chef-solo)? chef-zero is a bit more compatible to the chef-client speaking to the chef-server, so I see no reason to use chef-solo personally. Both read their cookbooks etc from the local disk (or a URL) and it doesn't matter, if that is a git repo or a downloaded archive (on the disk).